# Web-crawler for facebook in python

Tags: python, web-crawler, python-webbrowser

I am tring to work with web-Crawler in python to print the number of facebook recommenders. for example in this article from sky-news(http://news.sky.com/story/1330046/are-putins-little-green-men-back-in-ukraine) 
there are about 60 facebook reccomends. I want to print this number in the python program with web-crawler.
 i tried to do this, but it doesn't print anything:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_single_item_data(item_url):
    source_code = requests.get(item_url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    # if you want to gather information from that page
    for item_name in soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'pluginCountTextDisconnected'}):
        try:
                print(item_name.string)
        except:
                print("error")

get_single_item_data("http://news.sky.com/story/1330046/are-putins-little-green-men-back-in-ukraine")
```

Comment: If it prints nothing, then either all `item_name.string`s are `''`, or `soup.findAll` returns empty. So why don't you try a simple debug like `found = soup.findAll(...); print(found)`?

Comment: If it doesn't print anything, obviously the `for` loop is executing 0 times, which means `soup.findAll` isn't returning anything, which means there are no `<span>` elements with that class. So… looking at the `soup`, what makes you think such elements exist? Can you post a stripped-down example of an HTML document that you think should work with this code, but doesn't? (See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).)

Comment: Also, it worries me that you're using `findAll`, which was an "effectively deprecated" name in the late BS 3.x days, and is now a "legacy" name. This implies that you're copying and pasting some really ancient code (or following a very out-of-date tutorial), and if so, there are likely going to be a lot of problems.

Comment: abarnert, I am studying from thenewboston series that has been released 2 days ago

Comment: @Yagel any particular reason you can't just use the FB API? (Been a while since I've used it, but I think it had a way of getting likes related to external sites)

Comment: I am not familiar with the fb api

Answer (score 3):

The Facebook recommends loads in an `iframe.` You can follow the `iframe` src attribute to that page, and then load the span.pluginCountTextDisconnected's text:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://news.sky.com/story/1330046/are-putins-little-green-men-back-in-ukraine'
r = requests.get(url) # get the page through requests
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text) # create a BeautifulSoup object from the page's HTML

url = soup('iframe')[0]['src'] # search for the iframe element and get its src attribute
r = requests.get('http://' + url[2:]) # get the next page from requests with the iframe URL
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text) # create another BeautifulSoup object

print(soup.find('span', class_='pluginCountTextDisconnected').string) # get the directed information
```

The second requests.get is written as such due to the `src` attribute returning `//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fnews.sky.com%2Fstory%2F1330046&send=false&layout=button_count&width=120&show_faces=false&action=recommend&colorscheme=light&font=arial&height=21`. I added the `http://` and ignored the leading `//`.

---

[BeautifulSoup documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start)
[Requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-request)

Comment: I dont really understand this 3 lines of code and what this do: 1.BeautifulSoup(r.text)
 2.soup('iframe')[0]['src']
 3.requests.get('http://' + url[2:])        I just yesterday started to learn python, thank you

Comment: @Yagel I added comments to several of the lines and two links for you to use.

Comment: (I hope you will see this post...)I understand your answer, but when I tried to use it on this website for example-(http://tech.walla.co.il/?w=/4028/2782391) it doesn't work. I tried to change the code but it didn't work. thx

Comment: On that website, there are multiple `iframe` elements. You'll need to modify your code to search for the `iframe` with a `src` attribute that contains `facebook` or some other proper identifier.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook recommends are loaded dynamically from javascript, so they won't be available to your HTML parser. You will need to use the Graph API and FQL to get your answer directly from Facebook.

[Here is a web console](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=%3Fid%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.imdb.com%3Ffields%3Dlikes&version=v2.1) where you can explore queries once you have generated an access token.