# python web scraping for facebook shares

Tags: python, facebook, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

i am trying to crawl article in certain website (e.g. BBC or CNN) and print the number of facebook-recommendations. I asked this question already, and I got answer([Web-crawler for facebook in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675998/web-crawler-for-facebook-in-python)):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://news.sky.com/story/1330046/are-putins-little-green-men-back-in-ukraine'
r = requests.get(url) # get the page through requests
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text) # create a BeautifulSoup object from the page's HTML

url = soup('iframe')[0]['src'] # search for the iframe element and get its src attribute
r = requests.get('http://' + url[2:]) # get the next page from requests with the iframe URL
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text) # create another BeautifulSoup object

print(soup.find('span', class_='pluginCountTextDisconnected').string) # get the directed information
```

This code works fine, but when I tried it in this article(http://tech.walla.co.il/?w=/4028/2782391 - that currently has 250 recommendations) it didn't work, even when I tried to change the code a little bit.  when I press ctrl+U I see the code, but I cant find the number of shares. but when I click rightClick+inspectElement I can see the number of recommendations. Maybe there is a way to get the inspectElement, or you have another way?

Comment: Use the Graph API: http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://tech.walla.co.il/?w=/4028/2782391

Comment: thank you its helped me(: , but I still want to know if it is possible to use python to do this task and use the inspectElement

Comment: The DOM is updated with JavaScript. Unless you want to render the whole page and execute the JavaScript with something like Selenium or Ghost.py, just use the Graph API.